# How to unwrap duplicate objects in blender to export to substance painter

Tags: texturing, uv, baking

I am making a backpack in blender based off a tutorial by 3dex on YouTube. In the tutorial he uses Maya to unwrap and export and for his repeat objects he says that he "offsets the uv's because substance painter sometimes doesn't bake overlapping UV's". He says that he moves the uv's to another quadrant. Does anyone know how to do this in blender? I have attached images of the duplicate objects so that you can see what I am referring too.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the UV's of the duplicated object, hit <kbd>N</kbd> to open up the *UV Vertex* panel and add (or subtract) `1` to the X or Y coords (the direction doesn't matter):

[image]

Consider that if your asset is *not be used* in a game or any real-time application, there is no reason to set it up that way. You'd save some texture space this way but you would lose the opportunity to texture each object/dupe differently so I'd suggest just go with [UDIMs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/workflows/udims.html) and place your UVs accordingly (painter can handle UDIMs as of the latest versions).